# Yii разделение большого кода

Tags: yii

В Yii новичок. Скажите, пожалуйста, код можно разделить большой код в файле. Т.е сделать типа include('операция.php') или  include('операция2.php'); Как-то так. Спасибо

Желательно пример!

Comment: О каком коде речь? Модель? Контроллер? Представление?

Comment: Контроллер

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону использования `CAction`

тут есть пример: [Actions code reuse with CAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/170/actions-code-reuse-with-caction/)

Answer (score 0):

Если операция1 и операция2 - разные экшины, то CAction - то, что надо.
+ Получаете повторное использование в нужных контроллерах.